# iPhone 4S photos app not working

Tags: applications, photos, iphone

I got my iPhone 4S a week ago since I got it, it seems I can't open the photo app.

I can't see the pictures I have taken. Whenever I try to open the photo app, a white screen appears for two seconds then closes by itself.

The videos I record don't seem to appear on the video app as well. The video app opens, but it shows that it is empty.

I tried to reset the device but it didn't help.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: So, you've never run the Photo app successfully since getting this iPhone. Where did the pictures you took come from? Did the pictures you took come from another phone?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your best choice is to do an OS restore through iTunes if you can.  If that does not work, I'd contact Apple Support.

Also, for the record, videos that you take using the Camera app do not appear in the Videos app, they appear in the Photos app as well (strange, I know).